# Sum of quotients when all array elements is divided by each array elements

Tags: arrays, math

Came across a question in the coding test, suppose we have array, `arr = [4,3,8]`. Dividing array by 4 gives 1(4/4) + 0(3/4) + 2(8/4) = 3. Similarly by 3 gives 4 and by 8 gives 1. So the output is 3+4+1 = 8. `O(n2)` solution gave TLE, so I tried to do better.

I thought of sorting and using lower bound. Lower Bound of `arr[i]*k`, for `k = 1,2,3...`, till `arr[i]*k<=max(arr)`, will give me number of elements greater than the multiple taken, this will add in the final result. But this gave me wrong answer. How can I solve this problem efficiently, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You idea could work, perhaps implementation is not good.

Comment: @MBo I tried writing this down in exam, it gave wrong ans, platform didn't show on what cases it was wrong

Comment: You can write  also simple quadratic solution and compare results for some inputs.

Comment: @MBO will do that, will get back to you if I face any problem.

Comment: @MBO Can you please review this approach, its working fine for smaller cases. Please let me know [link](https://www.ideone.com/DIxyvB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want (in this example) three arrays which are the orignal array divided (with whole number division) by each of its three elements and then sum over them.

```
arr = [4,3,8]
sum([el//i for i in arr for el in arr])
```

will give you the wanted result. For understanding, the resulting list is:

```
In [8]: [el//i for i in arr for el in arr]
Out[8]: [1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1]
```

Summing over this gives the result `8`. If you really need the three arrays seperate and not concatenated in this way, I will edit this answer.

**EDIT** So I misunderstood the question, sorry. If you are allowed to use numpy, I would propose this algorithm, which (I think) still is O(n²), but overall much faster:

```
arr = np.random.randint(1,10,n)
np.sum(np.tile(arr, n)//np.repeat(arr,n))
```

Maybe I can come up with something more intelligent tomorrow

**EDIT 2** Sorting actually is a good idea and speeds up the algorithm a bit. I tested the three solutions so far with this litte script (I know, that `time.time` is not good for exact times, but it just shows the general speed of each algorithm):

```
for n in range(100, 500):
    arr = np.random.randint(1,10,n)
    #sorted
    t = time.time()
    arr2 = sorted(arr)
    sum([el1//el2 for i, el2 in enumerate(arr2) for el1 in arr2[i:]])
    t2 = time.time()-t
    times_sorted.append(t2)

    #standard
    t = time.time()
    arr = sorted(arr)
    sum([el1//el2 for el2 in arr for el1 in arr])
    t2 = time.time()-t
    times_standard.append(t2)

    #numpy
    t = time.time()
    arr = sorted(arr)
    np.sum(np.tile(arr, n)//np.repeat(arr, n))
    t2 = time.time()-t
    times_numpy.append(t2)
    if not n%50:
        print(n)
```

Plotting with

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(times_numpy)
plt.plot(times_sorted)
plt.plot(times_standard)
plt.legend(["numpy", "sorted", "standard"])
plt.xlabel("n")
plt.ylabel("time in s")
```

Gives:

[image: comparison]

Comment: It is obviously possible to get the number using a straightforward quadratic algorithm. The problem (even though OP didn't clearly articulate it) is to do it more efficiently.

Comment: I only need sum, O(n2) solution is pretty obvious and yeah it gave TLE, I think this complexity can be improved by using some pre-processing in array, though I have no idea how to do that

Comment: @TISHANTCHANDRAKAR Sorting is already `nlog(n)` so unless you can process each number in the sorted list in logarithmic time, I don't see how you can do better than quadratic. Perhaps an algorithm which somehow combines the sorting and the computing of the number.

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't think its possible to do simultaneously sorting and computing. As I mentioned in question, do you think sorting the list helps? As for any i from 0 to n, I don't have to divide for 0 to i-1 as I know the answer will be zero.

Comment: @TISHANTCHANDRAKAR sorting seems like a reasonable idea. As far as combining the two steps, perhaps a variation on merge-sort could work.

Comment: Can you use numpy?

Comment: @JohnColeman I implemented something like this, it works fine for smaller cases, [link](https://www.ideone.com/DIxyvB) , Can we do better? About your merge sort idea, can you share some insights of your approach.

Comment: @user8408080 how do you plan to use numpy to solve this problem?

Comment: @user8408080 Thanks man, this graph gave me general idea about the algo, your method using numpy is definetly very good but in interview, the question arises of time complexity and its better to give the O(nlogn) solution.